# What happened to the one-eyed twins after they escaped?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Last we saw them, the one-eyed twins who seemed to be against Aogiri and the CCG were terribly wounded and struggling to escape Cochlea prison, while the CCG and Aogiri battled during a prison break of every ghoul held in Cochlea. Amon saw them escaping but did they even really get out of that maximum security ghoul prison? Did they get caught in the crossfire, or caught by the CCG's reinforcements? What exactly happened to them?

Answer (score 2):

Kurona decided to flee with her Nashiro (who was fatally wounded), to find Kanou(the doctor) so he could save her.There he was found with Eto and Matasaka Kamishiro. Kanou stated that Nashiro's damage was beyond recovery and that they should leave her. Despite the terrible news, he smiled and said that Kurona would make many new friends. Kurona, shocked, fell to her knees still holding Nashiro. Kanou then left with Aogiri.

Sometime later, a distraught Kurona decided to consume her fatally wounded sister through her kagune as a last resort to save her from dying, but unknowingly killed Nashiro.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]